# Return json data from Function

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I use a function for Fetch with below code :

```
var URL='...'

export function PostData(method,data){
    fetch(URL+method,{
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify(data),
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},

    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        var ret=JSON.stringify(response)
        return ret
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
    })
}
```

and use it like below :

```
var retData=PostData('login/Authenticate',data)
```

**retData** is empty but in function **ret** has data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `PostData` function does currently not return anything, so it is empty.
First step would be to add a `return` statement:

```
export function PostData(method,data){
  return fetch(URL+method,{
    method:'POST',
    ...
```

This will make your function return a value, but not just a simple value, but a promise! Promises are not the easiest to understand, but there is also a of people who tried to explain them
 - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises
 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Now how can you use the value anyway?

```
PostData('login/Authenticate',data)
.then(retData => {
  // ... use retData here
});
```

Now, you used the react-native tag, so I am assuming you want to use this value in your `render` function. You can't do this simply by putting the `PostData` call in your `render` function. You'll have to put it in state, and then use that value in `render`:

```
state = { retData: null }

componentDidMount() {
  PostData('login/Authenticate',data)
  .then(retData => {
    // This puts the data in the state after the request is done
    this.setState({ retData: retData });
  });
}

render() {
  let retData = this.state.retData;
  // ... use retData in your render here, will be `null` by default
```

There are a lot more different or cleaner ways to do this, but I tried to keep this answer as simple and bare as possible :)

Comment: Thank you , i can access json's item with retData['Message'] why?

Comment: Keep in mind that the first run (before the PostData is "complete"), the retData will be `null`.
You can put a check in your render function like
`if (retData == null) { return <div>Loading</div>; }`

Answer (score 1):

It is empty at this point because the call to `fetch` is asynchronous and the literal is set to `undefined` as it moves to the next statement because it has not been resolved yet. One way around it is to return the promise object itself and then use `.then` to get the response once it is resolved.

```js
var URL = '...'

export function PostData(method, data) {
  // return the promise object
  return fetch(URL + method, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },

    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      var ret = JSON.stringify(response)
      return ret
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}

PostData('login/Authenticate',data).then(response => {
   // do something with the response
});
```

A cleaner approach would be is to use the `async/await` ES7 feature which makes it more readable.

```js
var URL = '...'

export function PostData(method, data) {
  // return the promise object
  return fetch(URL + method, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },

    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      var ret = JSON.stringify(response)
      return ret
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}

async function getData() {
    let retData = await PostData('login/Authenticate',data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , i can access json's item with retData['Message'] why?

Comment: That is because `retData` is an object that contains a key `Message`

Comment: sorry, I can't access it with retData['Message']